# Does frontswap handles only anonymous pages or both anonymous and dirty pages?

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel

I am currently working on frontswap which uses zswap to compress RAM pages and store in RAM. There is one doubt regarding the pages it consider to do that.
I read about frontswap at https://lwn.net/Articles/386090/ and at https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/frontswap.txt. It says that it handle swap pages but it never mention clearly that it uses anonymous pages or dirty pages or both. From my understanding.

Anonymous pages are those pages which are created when space requirement increase in your program. For example suppose you have declare a large matrix to do some processing. So when you allocate memory for this matrix then this memory is corresponding to some RAM pages we call these pages anonymous as these pages are not containing data which are file mapped.

Dirty pages are those pages which we load from secondary storage to our RAM and during the life of process we modify that page.

Please correct me if I am wrong about the above two definition.

Frontswap is present present as hook in swap_readpage() and swap_writepage() function in page_io.c. So, what I really want to know that what kind of pages are passed through these function call?